# Azure Front Door and X-Forwarded-Proto

Tags: azure, reverse-proxy, azure-front-door

Is it possible to set `X-Forwarded-Proto` header to https (I belive by default it's `http`). I have an application behind AFD that is configured with SAML that requires such header in order to properly direct call back.

I was going to use rules engine configuration to configure response header, but it's not allowed (see the picture).

[image: Rules engine configuration]

Any suggestions? Much appreciated.